# Why are women on right side of room by a funeral & left side by weddings?

Tags: minhag, wedding, funeral-burial-levaya

I just came from an orthodox funeral & noticed that the women were on the right side of the room & the men on the left. By weddings however it's the opposite with men on the right & women on the left. What is the reason for this? I have noticed this at other funerals as well so it wasn't a fluke. I would appreciate a source for this custom.

Comment: Wedding on the left is easy as that is the side the mother stands on when walking her daughter down and the side the kalla stands on when facing the messader. Why? So as to give honor to the husband/ groom to stand on the right. Funeral though. Hmmm. It does seem to hold true. +1.

Comment: Are women usually on the left by davening?

Comment: @SAH in many Shuls I have been to the women are commonly upstairs. I don't know whether they are usually to the left when on the same floor as the men.

Comment: @SAH FWIW - My shul is a combo of mixed and separate seating. The middle is mixed. When facing the ark, women are on the right and men are on the left, however, when entering the shul, the men's section is first and women are opposite the entrance. (I.e. - the shul doors are perpendicular to the ark.) In the few "shuls" (most are actually classrooms) that have a mechitzah down the middle, it seems women are on the right. (Continued next comment)

Comment: @SAH IIIRC, the reason for that is that when the chazzan who carries the Torah comes down from the bimah, he should go to his right as he faces the cong. (meaning the congregation's left). Thus, this would bring him into the men's section.

Comment: @user6591 Post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @DanF it only answers half the contradiction. Which isn't worth much.

Comment: @user6591 can you clarify what you mean "So as to give honor to the husband/ groom to stand on the right"? You mean to the right of the Groom?

Comment: @Earl according to the Talmud when two people walk side by side, the one deserving of honor goes on the right.  When three people walk abreast the most important goes in the middle, 2nd to his right and the 3rd on the list goes (all the way) to the left. Here although the parents are giving honor to their son the groom as he is in the middle, it seems fitting (standard practice) that the father stands to the groom's right.

Comment: @user6591 ok I understand. However in this case why would we honor the groom any more than the bride? We stand up for both of them when they walk down the isle. The bride is called a queen as much as the groom is a king?

Comment: @Earl we honor her too. But between her and her husband the groom, he gets more honor so he goes on the right of the two of them.

Comment: @Earl related to standing up https://www.ou.org/jewish_action/11/2016/whats-truth-standing-chatan-kallah/

Comment: I've answered the morbid side. From the various comments, it seems that *someone* should be able to answer the happy side.

Comment: @DanF I see your logic & it makes sense from the funeral point of view. I am not sure yet about the wedding part of my question though.

Comment: perhaps comment for meta but is 1/2 an answer good enough or is it all or nothing?

Comment: @Earl Indeed, it is a partial answer. If I can locate something for the wedding part, I'll edit it in. However, it seems that from other comments, most have a good answer. They are welcome to edit my answer & include theirs, or they can issue a partial answer for just the wedding. Keep in mind, that you don't need to accept or even vote on an answer immediately. And, by all means, you can post your question on meta, as well. So, you have loads of choices and freedom, here...

Answer (score 3):

I never paid attention to this until you mentioned this now.

I think the reason for that funeral arrangement makes sense, having been to a few too many funerals, lately.

Many funeral chapels have two sets of doors. The rows of benches face the front of the room. One enters the chapel from the "lobby", which would be to the right when facing the front of the room. The doors on the opposite side of the room usually lead to the parking lot where the hearse is waiting. These are the doors on the left side of the room when you would be facing the front of the room.

As it is usually the men who escort the hearse, and they would be the ones leaving the chapel first, it makes sense to have them seated closest to these doors on the left side of the room.

I'm unaware of any halacha that dictates any seating arrangement, so what I stated is based on what I have seen in chapels. On rare occasions, have I attended a funeral held in a shul. (Personally, I don't like the idea of doing this.) But, then, again, most Orthodox shuls have the women upstairs or in the back, anyway.

Comment: Are all (or significantly more than 50% of) funeral homes arranged in this way?

Comment: @Daniel I'm not a funeral director - It's a dying art, admittedly <** groan **> So, I certainly wouldn't know how even 25% of those around the NYC metro area are arranged. But, I'd say that in my dead friends' / relatives' end-of-life time, I've been to about 40 places and the majority are arranged this way.

Comment: @DanF +1. I am holding off on accepting for now being that it is a partial answer. I like the logic of your answer though.

Comment: @Earl Appreciate it. I sometimes have faulty logic; more often it's "twisted" b/c of all the years of Talmudic study :-) Here, I think the arrangement makes sense, and, again, it' s based on about 50 places that I have seen. It's not a universal arrangement, obviously. And, no funeral director has told me this reasoning. I'm not in the habit of conversing with funeral directors. Usually, their conversations don't lead to anywhere interesting :-)

Comment: @DanF usually Talmud sharpens the logic so keep studying by all means :)